"Noetherianess" of $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathbb{F}_{p,\square})$
In classical commutative ring theory it is quite immediate to see, that a field is noetherian in the following sense:
For any finitely generated $k$-vectorspace $M$, any sub-object is finitely generated again.
Now considering the category $\mathrm{Solid}^{\mathrm{light}}_{\mathbb{F}_p}$, proving the same statement feels a lot harder:
For any finitely generated solid $\mathbb{F}_p$-module $M$, any sub-object $N\hookrightarrow M$ is finitely generated.
Here finitely generated means, that one gets a surjection from the compact projective generator $\prod_\mathbb{N} \mathbb{F}_p\twoheadrightarrow M$. I've been trying to construct a map $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{F}_p\twoheadrightarrow N$ which commutes with the inclusion $N\hookrightarrow M$ but couldn't get very far with that.
I think one actually needs to use the $\mathbb{F}_p$-module structure, as the statement I want to show doesn't hold in classical commutative algebra for any ring $R$.

Do you expect this to be true?  Naively (without familiarity with solid abelian groups), I would expect that the infinite ascending chain $\mathbb F_p \subseteq \mathbb F_p^{\oplus 2} \subseteq \dots \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb F_p$ shows that the projective generator is not Noetherian.

Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category with a compact projective generator $P$.  Then $\mathcal A$ is equivalent to ${\rm Mod} R$ for the ring $R = {\rm End}(P)$ by an equivalence taking $P$ to $R$.  Therefore $\mathcal A$ is noetherian in the sense of every submodule of a finitely generated being finitely generated (in the sense of admitting a surjection from a sum of copies of $P$) if and only if it is Noetherian in the sense that every ascending chain of submodules of $P$ stabilizes.
Therefore, the infinite ascending chain $$\mathbb F_p \subseteq \mathbb F_p^{\oplus 2} \subseteq \dots \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb F_p$$
shows that the category of solid vector spaces is not Noetherian.  (The filtered colimit in the category of solid vector spaces gives a non finitely generated submodule-- if someone knows what this colimit is, I would be interested to see a description, since I would have thought this would be the whole space).

To my question from before: I think it is just $\oplus_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb F_p$, which is in fact solid.
